# How can I change the CSS of form inputs and then get the new CSS values with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I have been at this for two days and hope you can help.

I have a form with eight text input fields and three checkboxes. Here is the HTML for said form:

```
    <form name="sampleText" id="sample-text">
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" this-elem="h1" class="textStyleSamples" id="h1Sample" value="Level-1 Header Sample" />
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" this-elem="h2" class="textStyleSamples" id="h2Sample" value="Level-2 Header Sample" />
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" this-elem="h3" class="textStyleSamples" id="h3Sample" value="Level-3 Header Sample" />
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" this-elem="h4" class="textStyleSamples" id="h4Sample" value="Level-4 Header Sample" />
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" this-elem="pageText" class="textStyleSamples" id="pageTextSample" value="Page Text Sample" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" this-elem="aLink" class="textStyleSamples linkSamples" id="aLinkSample" value="Normal Link Sample" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" this-elem="aVisited" class="textStyleSamples linkSamples" id="aVisitedSample" value="Visited Link Sample" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" this-elem="aHover" class="textStyleSamples linkSamples" id="aHoverSample" value="Hovered Link Sample" />
        <br />
        <input class="ubem" id="underline" type="checkbox" /><u>Underline</u>
        <input class="ubem" id="bold" type="checkbox" /><b>Bold</b>
        <input class="ubem" id="italic" type="checkbox" /><em>Italic</em>
     </form>
```

I am trying to change the CSS of the input fields depending on whether or not the checkboxes are clicked. After that, I want to get the the new CSS for `text-decoration`, `font-weight`, and `font-style` and put these values into an array, where each of the 8 inputs has its own array.

Underline, bold, and italic are supposed to just be true or false.

I was able to get the text to change just fine after checking or unchecking the boxes, but when I tried to retrieve the new styles, I used `console.log()` and wasn't getting the correct values. Here is the jQuery I tried. I think I need an entirely new approach.

The way I had it set up initially was to enable the user to click on the checkbox, say, for `underline`, and then click on each input to change it to having underlined text. This did work, and I'd like to try to keep it this way, if possible. It was just the retrieval of newly-changed styles I was having issues with. I know there's a more elegant way of doing this, so any help I can get is much appreciated.

```
var thisElem = $(".textStyleSamples").attr("this-elem");
var sample = "Sample";

$(".ubem").change(function() {
    $(".textStyleSamples").each(function() {
        $("#" + thisElem + sample).on("click", function() {
            if ($("#underline").prop("checked")) {
                $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
            } else {
                $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
            }
            if ($("#bold").prop("checked")) {
                $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
            } else {
                $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
            }
            if ($("#italic").prop("checked")) {
                $(this).css("font-style", "italic");
            } else {
                $(this).css("font-style", "normal");
            }

        });
    });
});

var textElem = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "pageText", "aLink", "aVisited", "aHover"];
var isUnderlined = false;
var isBold = false;
var isItalic = false;
var styleArray = new Array(8);

$("#get_styles").on("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {     
        var cssPropUnderline = $("#" + textElem[i] + sample).css('text-decoration');
        if (cssPropUnderline.indexOf('underline') != -1) {
            isUnderlined = true;
        }
        var cssPropBold = $("#" + textElem[i] + sample).css('font-weight');
        if (cssPropBold.indexOf('bold') != -1) {
            isBold = true;
        }
        var cssPropItalic = $("#" + textElem[i] + sample).css('font-style');
        if(cssPropItalic.indexOf('italic') != -1) {
            isItalic = true;
        }
        styleArray[i] = [textElem[i] + sample, isUnderlined, isBold, isItalic];
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure if you are doing it with direct css for some other reason but i think its more standard to use classes with those css properties. `$(this).addClass("underline")` `$(this).removeClass('underline')`  `.underline { text-decoration: underline }`

Comment: Thanks. I'll change what I have to that, then. Would that solve my whole issue?

Comment: Well instead of `cssPropBold.indexOf('bold') != -1` you would do something like `$("#" + textElem[i] + sample).hasClass("bold")`